# Apache: Change XAMPP/PHP handle from application/x-httpd-php to application/x-httpd-php5

Tags: php, apache, configuration, xampp

My goal is to stop having to have a local copy and a live copy of my .htaccess file and instead be able to use the same single .htaccess file for BOTH local/live configurations. This will force me to better understand configuring a server.

My local server is XAMPP on my computer while my live server is a shared web host where I obviously can't change settings. I'm not at the point where I can configure everything from scratch so I'll be sticking with XAMPP for a while longer. Additionally anyone familiar with XAMPP should know that I attempted to use their forums (broken signin/password reset) and the admin hasn't responded to my email for days so I did try the more on-target route without success.

The more specific issue is I want to use my live shared server's PHP handler for my local server.

To execute PHP in non-native files on my live shared web host I use the following...

**public_html/.htaccess**

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .css .html .js .txt .xml
```

...I want to configure my computer/local setup to emulate this so I don't have to keep separate copies of .htaccess files for local/live (this forces me to learn how to configure the server). Currently I have to use the following locally...

**public_html/.htaccess**

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .css .html .js .txt .xml
```

I was able to track down where the configuration seems to be in XAMPP 1.7.7 (current latest release)...

**xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf**

Now I'm not interested in changing the PHP version that's being used (not my goal)...I just want to make sure that I can use the same handle locally as I do live. I tried to simply add the string '5' to line 17(?) below though that didn't work (saved, stopped server, restarted server of course).

```
<IfModule env_module>
    SetEnv MIBDIRS "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
    SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
    SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
    SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv PHPRC "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp"
</IfModule>

#
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/xampp/php/php5apache2_2.dll"

<FilesMatch "\.php$">enter code here
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>

#
# PHP-CGI setup
#
#<FilesMatch "\.php$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-cgi
#</FilesMatch>
#<IfModule actions_module>
#    Action application/x-httpd-php-cgi "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"
#</IfModule>


<IfModule php5_module>
    PHPINIDir "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/xampp/php"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/xampp/php/"
<Directory "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/xampp/php">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/xampp/cgi-bin">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler cgi-script
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/xampp/htdocs/xampp">
    <IfModule php5_module>
        <Files "status.php">
            php_admin_flag safe_mode off
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /security "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/xampp/security/htdocs/"
    <Directory "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/xampp/security/htdocs">
        <IfModule php5_module>
            <Files "xamppsecurity.php">
                php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
   </Directory>

    Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
    </Directory>

    Alias /webalizer "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/xampp/webalizer/"
    <Directory "C:/MEDIA/INTERNET/xampp/webalizer">
        <IfModule php5_module>
            <Files "webalizer.php">
                php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

So I don't know how to assign "**application/x-httpd-php5**" to work with whatever "**application/x-httpd-php**" is assigned to and remember I do not want to change the version of PHP I'm using (works fine).

I should also note that after using the program Advanced Find & Replace that I've found eight total files in the XAMPP directory with the string "application/x-httpd-php" however the file above is the only one that seems relevant to Apache's configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really an answer to your question, but I wouldn't do this to myself. Apache's config file format isn't really built for stuff like this.

To me, having two separate htaccess files (like `.htaccess` and `.htaccess.local`, and controlling the local server through the [`AccessFileName`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#accessfilename) directive:

```
AccessFileName .htaccess.local
```

is the best way to go.

If you really want to have everything in one file, it may be possible by using [`<IfDefine>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#ifdefine) blocks to separate local and live directives. You would have to set a define when starting your server locally, and could then test for the presence or non-presence of that define.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help me learn how to configure Apache and in this case PHP though AccessFileName I am easily presuming lets me change .htaccess to something else so I do appreciate you mentioning that however I can't accept this as the answer, will up-vote.

Comment: @John fair enough. I added a paragraph about how you may be able to achieve what you want. The thing is that the .htaccess format isn't really strong on stuff like conditional blocks - it really isn't designed for that - but maybe `IfDefine` can work for you, I've never worked with it so I can't say for sure

Comment: After spending time configuring everything this appears to be the best approach. I now keep use .local.htaccess and .htaccess files and a note of the configuration change locally in case I have to rebuild my server. Thanks!