# Apache localhost double www.domain (not host) directory rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have to provide public access in certain circumstances to a client domain from the main business domain. I'm working to get this to work locally first (`.local.htaccess`) and therefore only need help with the local system's rewrite rule please. These domains are *not* the host (host is `localhost`) though I test all manners of access (192.*, 127.*, etc).

**Requested URL**

`https://localhost/Version-1.0/www.example1.com/www.example2.com/images/waldo.gif`

**File Server Path**

`https://localhost/Version-1.0/www.example2.com/images/waldo.gif`

**.local.htaccess Location**

`https://localhost/Version-1.0/.local.htaccess`

The general code I've been tinkering with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[.*/].*/(www.)+/images/(.*)$ $1/images/$2
```

I've had success with the scripts directory (all rules, though not the images directory) using the following (the images directory even with an otherwise empty `.htaccess` file):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[^/].*/scripts(.+) scripts$1
```

Comment: @anubhava Updated the post.

Comment: @anubhava http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281029/apache-change-xampp-php-handle-from-application-x-httpd-php-to-application-x-ht#answer-9281094

Comment: It's localhost and it's `.local.htaccess` file is a separate file because the Apache configuration is different from the live server. On localhost of course I've edited the Apache configuration. Not sure why there is a need to over-complicate things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a *lot* of tinkering I was able to get the *rewrite* (not redirect) working!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*/(www..*)/images/(.+) $1/images/$2
```

**Understanding the Rewrite**

I loathe when people don't actually explain answers, most especially when the Q&A is far from simple so typical John will *explain* how this works. The key for me was *visualizing* how Apache regular expressions work. The image directly below is from the [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html).

[image: Apache Rewrite Regex]

1. **^**, start match here.
2. **.**, match any character.
3. *, any number of times. (.* match any character any number of times). This alleviates us from having to worry about directory/folder depth).
4. **/**, directory border.
5. **(www..*)**, the (parenthesis) create a group, the first group is assigned to $1, the second $2, etc. Matches the directory that starts with `www.`, the second period matches any character and again the immediate `*` matches any character any number of times (for dynamically working with any directory with any domain name).
6. **/images/**, matches the *images* directory, we don't want to match any other asset directory.
7. (.+), again a parenthesis group, this is assigned to `$2`. The **.+** matches any characters any number of times (for any file requested in this directory).
8. **$1/images/$2**, this is the second half of the rule. The first tests against the requested URI, if it matches this second half is what is requested on the server (presuming it exists/can be found). The parenthesis assigned are how we move things around so in essence we're throwing away everything *before* what is assigned to `$1`. The file name is assigned to `$2` (including any sub-directories).

The concept of assigning (parenthesis) to `$1`, `$2`, etc isn't difficult, it's ensuring that the regular expression not only matches correctly though also dynamically. That aspect also requires planning that comes with experience (how your project is organized in example).

Answer (score 2):

Try this rule as your very first rule in your `.local.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(Version-1\.0)/www[^/]*/(www[^/]*/\S*)\s
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Hm, none of the variations of that I tried worked. How would one English-to-regex write [any number of directory levels] + match "images/"? What the path (besides "images/") is and it's depth are irrelevant. It doesn't have to be exceptionally precise.

Comment: **BEAUTIFUL!!!** I changed part of it to `(Version.*)` to work across multiple versions. I greatly appreciate your help! Working answers on regex always help me expand my comprehension of it with useful scenarios.

Comment: Gah, I didn't realize that the double-domain path wasn't correctly set (it was single). I've recreated the paths I posted with your code though only the first path works, not the second (**comment edited**).

Comment: Is there a way to detect two instances of "www." and in this case discard the first instance and rewrite the path *that* way?

Comment: How about something like `RewriteRule ^/(www..*/images)/(.*) $1/images/$2` where the `www.` *and* the `/images/` are assigned to $1? Then how do we omit the first domain or...I feel like I'm on to something...

Comment: You can try this: `RewriteRule ^(.*/)?www\..*/(www\..*/images/.*) /$1/$2` to remove first `www`

Comment: The version number is variable...it seems `[^/].*` has been a generic way of dealing with `[whatever-this-directory-is]` in essence. Besides, the `.local.htaccess` file is inside of that directory (see post). So I'm trying to discard the contents except for the right-most `www.` match and group it with the `images/` to assign it to `$1` or `$2`. I'll try what you posted. To keep things as simple as possible I'm testing those exact conditions by the character/casing. Are you testing it too? I'll try what you posted.

Comment: Odd, after testing your snippet Apache reports `The requested URL /www.example2.com/images/waldo.gif was not found on this server.` ...but when I access that path *manually* (instead of the double-domain path) the image comes up. Hm...

Comment: Ah, I now realize that you were setting up a *redirect* when I needed to do a *rewrite*. I've got to test some HTML out and see if the image will load properly...

Comment: Yeah, I clarified I needed a rewrite and a redirect is only further complicating everything. Can you please help me with a rewrite? I did tag it as a rewrite, not redirect.

Comment: I figured it out! Check out my posted answer. Works dynamically and with sub-directories and everything! I didn't realize you were trying to setup a redirect and it might work though mod_rewrite has been tried and true for years. It's interesting to see what I tried versus what worked! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Rule that I gave in commentd above had no redirect flag: `RewriteRule ^(.*/)?www\..*/(www\..*/images/.*) /$1/$2`. I have checked your rule. It is not exactly what you asked as your regex is not even checking the presence of two `www` directories. Anyway whatever works for you.

Comment: I didn't actually need to check for two instances, just the request URL. Thanks for your help!